# Is it necessary to manually add <AutoGenerateBindingRedirect> metadata to the Core project file to correctly reference assemblies?

Tags: assemblies, xamarin, visual-studio-2013, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and MvvmCross to create an Android application using Portable Class Libraries.

I notice in my first view model, CatalogViewModel, some code is highlighted as not referencing the correct assemblies or unable to be resolved (the code builds fine even with these issues).

[image]

Examining the .NET Portable Subset assembly in the Object Browser shows various System assemblies included (2.0.5.0 v2.0.50727 & v4.0.30319, 4.0.0.0, 5.0.5.0). Automatic binding redirection for assemblies in .NET Framework 4.5.1 can be [enabled or disabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) by adding this line to the .csproj file.

```
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirect>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirect>
```

or

```
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirect>false</AutoGenerateBindingRedirect>
```

This seems to solve the referencing and redirection issues in the IDE. I haven't found any information about this manual modification to the Core project file in any of the MvvmCross info online I reviewed so I wanted to post a question here to see if anyone had some information or best practices.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you shouldn't need `AutoGenerateBindingRedirect`. This feature is intended to generate binding redirects for non-platform assemblies, such as NuGet packages. Platform assemblies should be unified automatically by Visual Studio / MSBuild.

Which seems to work, since you pointed out:

> the code builds fine even with these issues

So this looks like a bug in ReSharper. The fact that adding `AutoGenerateBindingRedirect` fixes your ReSharper issues might be a side effect of something else.